# How to properly maintain a collector car

Tags: maintenance

Im considering purchasing a brand new Corvette Z06 and I was simply wandering how I could best maintain for the long-haul. For example, what would be the appropriate miles to drive per week to maintain the engine as well as the value over time.

Comment: ............... 0 miles per week. Let's back up a minute. Every mile you drive any car decreases the resale value. If you want to buy a car just to make money off of it in 30 years, don't drive it at all. If you are asking how to care for a particular part of the car but you still need to drive it, please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real answer to that as it's a balance of enjoyment vs having it clutter up the garage.

If you are treating it as a collector's item as opposed to a car, put it in one of the climate controlled car storage bags and maybe pull it out once a year, if that. Usually, 40-50 years from now it's the delivery mileage, all original cars that tend to bring the most money.

If you're after getting as much "life" out of the car as possible, avoid short journeys, don't thrash it while the mechanical parts are still cold, don't take it out in bad weather, thoroughly clean it regularly and use high-quality parts for maintenance. Obviously, don't skimp on maintenance either.

Don't ignore the time-based part of the maintenance and base your maintenance on oil sampling etc rather than the manufacturer's schedule or the "Oh $DEITY, I haven't changed the oil this week" recommendations that you get from some people.

Answer (score 0):

The single best thing you can do is join a car club or active forum and talk with fellow enthusiasts.

The advice about how to keep it happy is going to have information specific for your car's make and model. For instance: I have a Porsche 924 and their injection system is known to get upset if you *don't* drive it regularly.